# Unable to establish One to Many Relations in MVC 6 Views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As a learning exercise, I was trying to form a simple One to many Relation between Vendors and Shops where each Vendor has multiple shops.

Using two model classes I achieved the following:

[image: Schema]

**This is what scaffolding gives me for Shops**

[image: ShopView]

Why am I not getting a drop down here?

Not sharing any code as of now. As most of it is auto generated. Let me know if someone would like me to paste the code for my models.

Another doubt why are my table Columns alphabetically Ordered? If I am not mistaking entity framework 6 used to order it as per the class definition. Is there a way to override it? Cause the view scaffold seems to mirror the DB in terms of ordering objects.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I added a property Vendorid in the Shops Class. Now I see the Dropdown but  no values. Do I need to get down to Fluent API for achieving this?

```
   public class Shops
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        public String Address  { get; set; }
        public Boolean Active { get; set; }
        public int VendorId { get; set; }
        public Vendors Vendor { get; set; }
    }
```

**Vendors**

```
public class Vendors
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Shops> Shops { get; set; }


}
```

Env: Visual Studio 2015 (Latest ASP.net Patch Applied).
Project Template: Web Application

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what approach on EF you are using. Are you sure they have relationship in their classes? If your using code first, you have to map it manually using fluent API. on OnModelCreating method on DbContext class, use something like this

modelBuilder.Entity().HasMany(v => v.Shop).WithOptional(s => s.Vendor).

If your using Database First, just create relationship on tables diagram(or script) and update the model on your project and EF will create it for you.

Comment: EF automatically relates your classes if you use the standard naming convention (Id or [Classname]Id), so fluent api is not mandatory. One more thing, add **virtual** keyword to your properties with relationship to other classes so EF will know they are to be part of a relationship.


public **virtual** Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

public **virtual** ICollection<Shops> Shops { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would try the same.

Comment: I took your advice no luck.

Comment: Did you delete and re-create the controllers/views scaffolding?

Comment: Yes of corse. Please look in to the matter.

Comment: You said your seeing dropdown but with no values. So EF is mapping it but it got no linked Vendor-Shop. Are you sure the FK Id's are linking or the same? Also pls take a look in the controller on getting the dropdown values. (or show it here.)